# What is '$' in python?

Tags: python, shell

As a beginner in Python, I'm reading a book written by Bill Lubanovic

I found something weird.

In that book, After saving simple code in test1.py, which is

```
print("This standalone program works!")
```

it says python can run it by typing in

```
$ python test1.py
```

However, whenever I try to use that, syntax error happens.

Although I know there are other methods like using exec() which I found in this website, I wanna know why book uses that method which doesn't work at least for me.

Comment: `$ ` denotes that the above command should be run on a terminal.

Answer (score 13):

It means you need to type everything but the `$` in *the terminal*.

```
python test1.py
```

It's just a convention though. Authors also use `> python test1.py` and other notations.

I don't know which version of his book you're reading, but he mentions it in [this version.](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449359362_sampler.pdf)

> In the example that follows, $ is a sample system prompt for you to type a command like python in the terminal window. We’ll use it for the code examples in this book, although your prompt might be different.

Comment: `>>>` refers to the prompt of an interactive Python session though.

Comment: @poke, I've removed that. Thanks

Comment: You could probably add that `$` refers to a normal user while `#` refers to root.

Answer (score 6):

You are not supposed to enter the `$`.

The `$` represents the shell/terminal prompt. This is the string of characters that appear in your terminal when it is waiting for input, although `$` typically indicates some flavour of unix, e.g. linux.

Your terminal will probably use a different prompt, e.g.

```
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Or, if you are using a Windows terminal you might see :

```
C:\>
```

or

```
C:\WINDOWS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered in following stackoverflow post:
[What does the $ mean when running commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986306/what-does-the-mean-when-running-commands)

[What does the $ mean when running commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986306/what-does-the-mean-when-running-commands)

> As of now, Python does not implement $ in its syntax. So, it has nothing to do with Python.
> Instead, what you are seeing is the terminal prompt of a Unix-based system (Mac, Linux, etc.)
>
> So basically is terminal prompt and you should type in only: **python test1.py** without $ sign. another example is **~** when using oh-my-zsh.

Comment: If you think, a question has an answer in another question, instead of copy/pasting it here, please flag this one as duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Lafexlos done. Thank you