# How are $ symbols used in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've been trying to understand how to use/install NodeJS recently, but have become confused by tutorials such as [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/) and their use of the `$` symbol. For example, the aforementioned tutorial says to use `$ which node` to check where on my system Node is installed. However, I have typed this into my Command Prompt (I'm running Windows) and it says that "$ is not recognised as an internal or external command". Why is this happening? I know that Node is installed, because `node -v` returns the version as it should.

Comment: in said tutorial, `node -v` would probably be represented as `$ node -v`

Comment: Same question but with regard to Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986306/what-does-the-mean-when-running-commands (The answer is also the same)

Comment: Okay, thanks. However, writing 'which node' returns "which is not recognised as..."?

Comment: Right, because that command isn't available in windows.

Comment: Your biggest problem following online documentation will be that they frequently use commands not available in windows. The $ sign is kind of a warning sign that they probably have Unix command lines in mind.

Answer (score 4):

A line starting with `$` means *run this in your terminal*. It's there because, historically, shells such as Bash have ended their prompts with the character `$` for normal users and `#` for super users (`root` account, basically).

It's for documentation and shouldn't be included in the command itself. It has nothing to do with Node.js specifically.

It's most common in documentation that is providing instruction for running a series of commands in your terminal, oftentimes providing expected output (denoted with lines *without* the `$` or `#` characters).

For example, the following documentation shows that running the following 5 commands (denoted by the `$` prefix) will produce the following output, or similar.

```
$ ls
package.json node_modules
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
$ mkdir lib
$ touch lib/hello.js
$ ls lib
hello.js
```

Note that this isn't *as* applicable on Windows - especially when seeing the `$` prefix. Sometimes, documentation targeting Windows specifically will start with `:\>` or `C:\>` instead of `$`, though that is much less common.